# substr_compare returning incorrect recults

Tags: php, string

In PHP manual given example is

```
echo substr_compare("abcde", "bcg", 1, 2); // 0
```

I tested the code and get the same result, but how "bc" and "bcg" can be equal? This should give -1. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php) carefully:

> `substr_compare()` compares `main_str` from position `offset` with `str` up to `length` characters.

You compare up to 2 characters from position 1 in `main_str` (`"abcde"`), which is `"bc"`, with `"bcg"`. But only **up to** 2 characters.

See also about the `length` parameter:

> The length of the comparison. The default value is the largest of the length of the `str` compared to the length of `main_str` less the `offset`.

I agree it could be misunderstood, but only *up to* `length` characters are compared.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, this function "compares **`main_str` from position `offset`** with `str` up to `length` characters."

So, 2 characters from "`abcde`", starting at position 1, would be "`bc`". And the first two characters of "`bcg`" are "`bc`" -- hence, `0` is returned.